# Threejs - rotation object around center

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have working solution with this code:

```
var collisionGroup = new THREE.Group();
scene.add( collisionGroup );

(function() {
  var geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 20, 32 );
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
  var collisionCircle = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  collisionCircle.position.z = -180;
  collisionGroup.add( collisionCircle );
})();

function animate(timestamp) {
  // apply camera rotation
  var rotObjectMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
  rotObjectMatrix.makeRotationFromQuaternion(camera.quaternion);
  collisionGroup.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(rotObjectMatrix);

  // Update VR headset position and apply to camera.
  controls.update();

  // Render the scene through the manager.
  manager.render(scene, camera, timestamp);

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

But i would like to know if it's possible to achieve this without creating group for every object i would like to rotate (there will be many of them).
Position for those object's are based on camera rotation amd this is why i've used makeRotationFromQuaternion and rotation.setFromRotationMatrix.

Maybe there is easier solution then storing camera quaternions.

Comment: The trick would be to modify your geometry and offset the position of each vertex beforehand. I haven't used Three.js in a while so I wouldn't be able to easily give you a direct example. But you can check the docs (look for the part for `position`) http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/BufferGeometry

Comment: Actually my mistake this would probably be the correct link http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Geometry and you would be looking for `translate`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a good alternative for what you want to achieve, but you could consider adding the objects to your camera (the camera is also an `THREE.Object3D` instance) directly. As children of the camera this will make their position and rotation relative to the position and rotation of the camera.